# Magento Navigation Header Class

Tags: css, magento, styles

I am trying to make more categories fit on my navigation bar. I want to do that by reducing the size of the margins on the existing categories. How can I do that? I'm guessing through styles.css but I can't isolate the variable that dictates it..

[image: image of what I'm trying to fix]

Comment: Use chrome's F12 element inspector,  or firebug plugin on firefox. In the lower right corner of the panel, there is magnifier in chrome, mouse pointer in firebug, click that, then select the element you want to inspect to find its relevent css.  you ll see css styles on the right.  try to select different elements until you find the one you need, and change the styles to see if it is what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a default Magento theme it is the following class:

```
#nav a { float:left; padding:5px 12px 6px 8px; color:#a7c6dd; font-weight:bold; }
```

Line 560 or styles.css.